# How do I write shell scripts in cygwin? (especially case statements/loops)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, cygwin

To learn how to write a shell script to complete a level on OverTheWire (Bandit) I've been going through the shell script tutorial at shellscript.sh.

It took me some time to figure out that since I use cygwin, I can't just write something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_MESSAGE="Hello World"
echo $MY_MESSAGE
```

without saving it to a file such as  var.sh

However, the way I have to write the code and save on cygwin is a lot different to how to how I see in most tutorials I've seen online because it seems everyone is either using GNU or Kali Linux.

The way I have to write this code on cygwin would have to be:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > var.sh
echo 'MY_MESSAGE="Hello World"' > var.sh
echo 'echo $MY_MESSAGE' >> var.sh
```

which is very cumbersome and slow (since I can only put one line of code before hitting return) compared to something like Kali Linux where it seems I would just be able to copy and paste the code from the tutorial.

Nevertheless, I've gotten desired results but I've hit an unmovable rock in the form of the case statement. The shell script I'm now trying to run looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read f
do
  case $f in
        hello)          echo English    ;;
        howdy)          echo American   ;;
        gday)           echo Australian ;;
        bonjour)        echo French     ;;
        "guten tag")    echo German     ;;
        *)              echo Unknown Language: $f         ;;
   esac
done < myfile
```

So far I've gotten nothing but syntax errors. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to format this. Could some please help me?

EDIT:

```
stoya@Home-PC ~
$ #!/bin/sh

stoya@Home-PC ~
$ while read f
> do
>   case $f in
>         hello)          echo English    ;;
>         howdy)          echo American   ;;
>         gday)           echo Australian ;;
>         bonjour)        echo French     ;;
>         "guten tag")    echo German     ;;
>         *)              echo Unknown Language: $f         ;;
>    esac
> done < myfile
```

This is what I get when I copy and paste the code from the tutorial to Notepad++ and then copying and pasting the code to cygwin.

After I hit enter I get this:

```
stoya@Home-PC ~
$ #!/bin/sh

stoya@Home-PC ~
$ while read f
> do
>   case $f in
>         hello)          echo English    ;;
>         howdy)          echo American   ;;
>         gday)           echo Australian ;;
>         bonjour)        echo French     ;;
>         "guten tag")    echo German     ;;
>         *)              echo Unknown Language: $f         ;;
>    esac
> done < myfile
Unknown Language:
```

Futhermore, I get the same result when I just copy and paste straight from the tutorial.

Comment: What prevents you from writing `var.sh` in an editor?

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by that (that's how little I know about all of this) or how I would even do that. If you mean putting it into notepad, and then copying and pasting in, that doesn't work.

Comment: `echo 'blah' > var.sh` writes `blah` into the file `var.sh`. You can use any editor (Notepad might not be the best choice, though - maybe have a look at VS Code or Notepad++) to edit `var.sh` directly and then run it with `./var.sh` (maybe after making it executable with `chmod +x var.sh`). I'm not sure I understand why you can't copy and paste the commands from the tutorial, though... what happens if you do that?

Comment: Using `cat` and a `heredoc`, would let you create a script you wanted. without using an editor, it's not as flexible as an editor but it gets the job done...

Comment: @Jetchisel Sorry if you think I'm aware of what to do with these functions. I'm really not. Heredoc is not a function recognised on cygwin.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Please see my edit above in the main post.

Comment: Regardless of what editor you chose to use, you have to be aware that there is a common problem for beginners relating to the "end-of-line" character (or characters!) used when saving the file. When using Notepad++ set 'Settings->New Document->Format (line endings)->Unix . Good luck.

Comment: Regarding your edit: does `myfile` exist? What's in it? Your command reads it line by line and compares each line to the different cases. It looks like it doesn't exist (or is empty) and you assign the empty string to `f`, hence the output you're getting.

Comment: after doing "ls", myfile exists but it is empty, you're right.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Basically, I'm not sure what should be in myfile.

Comment: On cygwin, make sure your shell script file is set to use LF instead of CR LF as the end of line. Install (if necessary) and use the `dos2unix` aka `d2u` program to convert a text file with CR LF endings to LF endings. Notepad++, Geany, and many other Windows editors will create files with LF endings and preserve or convert the ending.

Answer (score 2):

A shell script is a text file, so you need a text editor.
Windows Notepad is not good for this job as it can not handle file with LF (Line Feed) line terminations. It uses `CRLF` (Carriage Return Line Feed) as windows standard.

Recently I found Notepad++ a nice replacement for Notepad than can handle both the terminations. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/

Of course there are tons of text editors aiming to programmers that have such capability.

In Cygwin itself there are several text editors available and the most used is probably ViM. You can install it from the setup.

[image]

It is very powerful and there are tons of tutorial to learn how to use it.

Going to your example we need to write 2 files `myscript.sh` and `myfile`

```
$ vim myscript.sh
```

press `i` to enter in `insert mode`, write all your text than `ESC` to go in `command mode` and than `:wq` to write the file and quit.

[image]

in similar way we write the `myfile`

```
$ vim myfile
```

[image]

Than we add the executable flag to the script

```
$ chmod +x  myscript.sh
```

and run it

```
$ ./myscript.sh
English
American
Australian
French
German
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of vim, it's like you've handed me a magic wand. I guess I should call you Merlin lol. I was able to run the script as you've shown however, I was under the impression that this loop would allow me to input "hello" or "guten tag" and then I would be told which language the word is from. I'm guessing this isn't so because there aren't any variables requested ($x). Could you please confirm this? To everyone else, thanks for trying to help me, but I'm not well-versed enough in this to be able to use your help unfortunately.

Comment: See example of input during execution https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php